# "Eines des wichtigsten Amt" oder "eines der wichtigsten Ämter"?

Tags: grammar-identification, question

Ist dieser Satz grammatikalisch korrekt?

> ... ist eines des wichtigsten Amt in Europa.

Manche sagen es soll *eines der wichtigsten Ämter in Europa* sein.

Comment: As a side note: "ich komme nicht mehr damit zurecht" ia way too strong for such a question. You'd normally say something like "ich weiss nicht genau" or just "ich brauche eure Hilfe"

Comment: @marstato: Hilfsappelle gehören prinzipiell nicht in die Fragen, ebenso keine Dankesformeln und Grüße.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ....... ist eines des wichtigsten Amt in Europa.

This sentence is not correct. 
The other version

> eines der wichtigsten Ämter in Europa

is indeed correct.

You are talking about one of many like: *One of the student**s***

This is why it needs to be "Ämter" the plural.

EDIT: DE Version

> ....... ist eines des wichtigsten Amt in Europa.

Dieser Satz ist nicht richtig.
Die andere Version

> eines der wichtigsten Ämter in Europa

is die Richtige.

Du meinst ja eines von vielen, wie e*iner der **Schüler***

Deswegen muss auch Ämter im Plural stehen.

Comment: Stimmt, jetzt gibt es auch eine deutsche Version :)

Answer (score 6):

"Eines der ..." bezieht sich auf ein einzelnes Element einer Menge von ähnlichen Elementen. Somit steht die Angabe der Menge im Plural.

Daher muss es *Eines der wichtigsten Ämter* heißen, ebenso wie *eine der lästigsten Aufgaben* oder *einer der größten Rennfahrer*.

Answer (score 2):

Der Satzteil is nicht korrekt, weil Casus bzw. Numerus nicht stimmen. "Des" verlangt Genitiv, Singular, der ähnlichste korrekte Satz wäre also "... eines des wichtigsten Amtes". In dem Fall wäre etwas gmemeint, das dem wichtigsten Amt zugehörig ist oder gehört. Wenn das Amt selbst gemeint ist, dann ist ".... eines der wichtigsten Ämter" (Genitiv, Plural) korrekt.

Theoretisch wäre es auch möglich, etwas zu beschreiben, das den höchsten Ämtern zugehörig ist (z.B. ein Privileg), was auch "... eines der wichtigsten Ämter" lauten würde und nur duch den Kontext von der anderen Variante zu unterscheiden ist. z.B. "Das Privileg der Immunität ist eines der wichtigsten Ämter". Wahrscheinlich würde man eher etwas sagen wie: "Das Privileg der Immunität ist eines, das den wichtigsten Ämtern vorbehalten ist", was Akkusativ ist und eine gänzlich andere Satzstruktur hat, aber die erstgenannte Genitivform ist auch korrrekt.